# Background image added for div tag is not working... What are the possible approaches?

Tags: reactjs

I've used this approach in my code: it's NOT working.

```
const style={
  backgroundImage:'url("../assets/images/myimage.jpg")'
}
<div className={container} style={style} >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The path will not work like that. A simple solution would be this :

```
import img from '../assets/images/myimage.jpg'

const style={
  backgroundImage:`url(${img})`
}
<div className={container} style={style} >
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the image reference path is coming from API (it's a dynamic).